# Managing percentages of money columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, currency

I have a question about managing percentages of money columns in SQL Server. I have a simplified case like this:

```
CREATE TABLE _ROUNDERROR 
(
    Premium Money,
    Commission Money
)

INSERT INTO _ROUNDERROR (Premium, Commission) 
VALUES (1632.33, 408.08)

INSERT INTO _ROUNDERROR (Premium, Commission) 
VALUES (408.08, 163.23)
```

When I execute the following

```
SELECT
    *, 
    (Commission / Premium) AS RAWDIV, 
    CAST(Commission AS decimal) / CAST(Premium AS decimal) AS DECDIV, 
    ROUND(CAST(Commission AS decimal) /CAST(Premium AS decimal), 4) AS DECDIV4, 
    CAST(Commission AS float) / CAST(Premium AS float) AS FLODIV, 
    ROUND(CAST(Commission AS float) / CAST(Premium AS float), 4) AS FLODIV4
FROM
    _ROUNDERROR
```

These are the results of this query:

```
PREMIUM               COMMISSION            RAWDIV                DECDIV                                  DECDIV4                                 FLODIV                 FLODIV4
--------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1632,33               408,08                0,2499                0.2500000000000000000                   0.2500000000000000000                   0,249998468446944      0,25
408,08                163,23                0,3999                0.3995098039215686274                   0.3995000000000000000                   0,399995099000196      0,4
```

As seen above, if I divide the money columns SQL Server is ceiling the result. So, after reading some post about, I've tried to cast as decimal both columns before dividing them, and it works fine for the first pair of values (first row). But decimal is losing precision too (in second row), and I've decided to cast as float (see second row).

OK, it's working now, but it's the best solution? Is there any side-effect? I can't change the type of the fields because is a legacy database.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `decimal` isn't working for you is because you don't specify any scale and precision and so it defaults to `decimal(18,0)` and instantly loses any fractional part via rounding.

`CAST(1632.63 as decimal)` gives 1633 for example.

You should specify precision and scale suitable for the range that [`money`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) supports.

`decimal(19,4)` would represent `922,337,203,685,477.5807` exactly though you may want to reduce the precision if your money values are never anywhere near those limits.

```
SELECT
    *, 
    (Commission / Premium) AS RAWDIV, 
    CAST(Commission AS decimal(19,4)) / CAST(Premium AS decimal(19,4)) AS DECDIV, 
    CAST(Commission AS float) / CAST(Premium AS float) AS FLODIV
FROM
    _ROUNDERROR
```

Returns

```
+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| Premium | Commission | RAWDIV |        DECDIV         |      FLODIV       |
+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 1632.33 |     408.08 | 0.2499 | 0.2499984684469439390 | 0.249998468446944 |
|  408.08 |     163.23 | 0.3999 | 0.3999950990001960399 | 0.399995099000196 |
+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

(certainly if you are paying commission of `922,337,203,685,477` I'd likely want a job there dependent on the currency)

Comment: Ok, that's true, I haven't think about decimal precision! But what's better, float or decimal with more precision?

Comment: For monetary (and most) types of data, do not touch *float* with a barge-pole.

Comment: I'd generally default to using a precise datatype (decimal) vs an imprecise one (float) though for practical purposes it probably doesn't really matter here for dealing with the results of a division. You can see in the results that you have a few more decimal places from the decimal but I doubt those will make any difference to anything

Comment: once you divide a currency by a currency you no longer have a currency. You just have a number. e.g. 4 lots of £5 are £20 and £20/£5 is 4 - not £4